# Marshaling C# struct to C++ dll - different values

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a DLL written in C++ and I am trying to call a function that expects a struct from my C# project.

Here's its declaration

```
int _stdcall InitialiseMotors(int i_nBoard, Array_Of_Structures moveParameters)
```

And here is the declaration of the struct

```
typedef struct MoveMotorSolenoidParametersTag
{
    bool SetDirectionForMotor; 
    int SetNumberOfStepsForMotor;
    bool TurnSolenoidsON_OFF;
} MoveMotorSolenoidParameters;
```

The corresponding call in C#:

```
[DllImport(DllBeingUsed)]
private static extern int InitialiseMotors(int i_nBoard, 
DllDatatypes.MoveMotorSolenoidParameters moveMotorSolenoidParameters);
```

And the definition of my structure:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MoveMotorSolenoidParameters
    {
        public bool SetDirectionForMotor;
        public int SetNumberOfStepsForMotor;
        public bool TurnSolenoidsON_OFF;

        public MoveMotorSolenoidParameters(bool setDirectionForMotor = true, 
            int setNumberofStepsForMotor = 10,
            bool turnSolenoidsON_OFF = true )
        {
            SetDirectionForMotor = setDirectionForMotor;
            SetNumberOfStepsForMotor = setNumberofStepsForMotor;
            TurnSolenoidsON_OFF = turnSolenoidsON_OFF;
        }
    }
```

Even though I am passing the values true, 10 and true, my DLL seems to be getting different values. true, 167772160 and false. I can see these values by putting a breakpoint on the DLL. I checked the values before the DLL function is called and they are correct. So I am assuming something is happening during the marshalling.

[QuickWatch of C++ struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGtUc.png)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: 167772160 is 10, shifted left by 24 bits (3 bytes).  In other words, the C++ bool takes 1 byte and the structure is packed tight.  Use [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)] on the struct and [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] on the bool members.

Comment: You might also consider specifying the layout of the c++ struct. My understanding is that c++ does not guarantee any particular layout, so it could change between compilers or platforms . See [pragma pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-170)